# Who was Makardhawaj?

Tags: ramayana, rama, hanuman

When Lord Hanuman went to Patal Lok to save Lord Rama and Lakshmana from Ravana's brother Ahivaravan,he saw a demon who was a guard of Patal Lok named 'Makardhawaj'. Who was the demon Makardhawaj?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanuman#Patala_incident  may be this is use full for you "Makardhawaj" is son of Hanuman